# Azure: circular (ring) queue with unique key

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

For my app I need to organize a circular (ring) queue. It means that any processed message immediately goes to the end of the queue for continuous processing.

For example:

1. Queue: `A`, `B`, `C`.
2. Receiver processes `A`.
3. Queue: `B`, `C`, `A`.

2 and 3 should be performed atomically. So we never lose `A` or any other message.

Another requirement is to ignore duplicates. So there should be always a single `A` in the queue. Even if a sender pushes another `A` item. `A` refers to some unique (primary) key of the message here.

I looked for using Azure Service Bus, but I cannot find how to meet both requirements with it. Is it possible to implement the scenario with Service Bus? If not, what are best alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of queue can be implemented with Service Bus **sessions**. Sessions provide "group by" mechanics, so we can assign our unique key to `SessionId` of the message and then receive messages in groups ignoring all messages in a group except the first one.

**Implementation**

1) Create a queue with `RequiresSession` set to true:

```
var queueDescription = new QueueDescription("CircularQueue")
{
    RequiresSession = true,
};
await namespaceManager.CreateQueueAsync(queueDescription);
```

2) When sending message to the queue, set `SessionId` to your unique key value:

```
var message = new BrokeredMessage($"Message body")
{
    MessageId = "MESSAGE_UNIQUE_KEY",
    SessionId = "MESSAGE_UNIQUE_KEY"
};
await queueClient.SendAsync(message);
```

3) Receive messages using sessions:

```
while (true)
{
    var session = await queueClient.AcceptMessageSessionAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
    if (session == null)
        continue;

    try
    {
        var messages = (await session.ReceiveBatchAsync(100)).ToList();

        if (messages.Count == 0)
            continue;

        var message = messages[0];

        ProcessMessage(message);

        await queueClient.SendAsync(message.Clone());
        await session.CompleteBatchAsync(messages.Select(msg => msg.LockToken));
    }
    finally
    {
        await session.CloseAsync();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the little I know about Azure Service Bus, I believe both of these requirements can be fulfilled with it individually, though I am not sure how both of them can be fulfilled together.

> Message Cycling

It is my understanding that Azure Service Bus supports `First-In-First-Out (FIFO)` behavior. What you could do is fetch the message (say A) from the top of the queue in `Receive and Delete` mode and then reinsert the message back in the queue. Since you're creating a new message, it will be posted to the end of the queue.

> Avoid Duplicate Messages

Service Bus Queues has a boolean property called [`RequiresDuplicateDetection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.queuedescription.requiresduplicatedetection.aspx) and setting this value accordingly will prevent duplicate messages being inserted. A simple search for `Azure Service Bus Duplicate Detection` will lead you to many examples.

Comment: There are some problems with this implementation: 1) Using "Receive and Delete" can causing losing messages if something happens between receiving and reinserting the message (can be fixed with peak-lock mode). 2) Duplicate Detection implementation in Service Bus ignores duplicates even if the previous message was already processed. So we lose messages here. 3) Duplicate Detection also has 7 days limit so if we overcome this limit, it won't work and we even won't know about it.

Comment: I would agree with you on all the points you mentioned above. "Receive and Delete" definitely poses a potential "message lost" problem. But I am not sure how would "Peek & Lock" would work with "Duplicate Detection" as the message is still there in the queue. I would be very curious to know what solution you finally come up with :).

Comment: Yes, the duplicate messages is a real problem. It looks like it's impossible to implement it correctly with Service Bus. Looking for other options: SQL Azure, Redis.

Comment: It looks like duplicate detection can be implemented using sessions in Service Bus. The unique key should be set as SessionId property. Then accepting session all duplicate messages are also retrieved with the original one. Looks weird, but should work here.

Comment: Published solution as an answer.